# Mutating objects in Redux payloads outside of reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

The Redux documentation takes a lot of time to explain how we should avoid mutating the state in reducers.

But the actions themselves aren't automatically deep-copied, or are they?

If we do something like this:

```
  ....
  switch (actions.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_PROP1':
      return {
        ...state,
        prop1: actions.payload.obj1
      }
  ....
```

this seems to be a (part of a) pure function.

But if `obj1` is not primitive, and instead an object for which we retain a reference from the outside, and we mutate the object behind this reference, will we also mutate the state and get the same undefined behavior?

So is it basically another contract that we don't mutate action? Or can it be safely done?

Comment: If you `dispatch({payload: {obj1: {}}})`, then `action.payload.obj1` is a new reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Redux documentation takes a lot of time to explain how we should
> avoid mutating the state in reducers.

Yes, that they do. It's to make it overtly clear you shouldn't be mutating your state/actions/etc.

> But the actions themselves aren't automatically deep-copied, or are
> they?

No, action objects are just plain old Javascript object with some required/expected properties, e.g. `type` and `payload`. They are dispatched to the store and passed though the reducer tree to effect the update to the next state.

> If we do something like this:
>
> ```
> ....
> switch (actions.type) {
>   case 'UPDATE_PROP1':
>     return {
>       ...state,
>       prop1: actions.payload.obj1
>     }
> ....
> ```
>
> this seems to be a (part of a) pure function.
>
> But if `obj1` is not primitive, and instead an object for which we
> retain a reference from the outside, and we mutate the object behind
> this reference, will we also mutate the state and get the same
> undefined behavior?

Yes, if you save the `actions.payload.obj1` reference to `state.prop1` and later mutate `actions.payload.obj1` value elsewhere in the reducer tree (*e.g. another reducer function*) or even all the way back out in the UI code, then `state.prop1` will be "mutated". Similarly since `state.prop1` is a reference to the action's payload, if you mutate the `state.prop1` value it can change the `actions.payload.obj1` value other reducers be reading.

> So is it basically another contract that we don't mutate action?

Yes, it's another contract to not mutate objects being passed around. This is effectively a hard rule in React: "Though shalt not mutate anything!". Don't mutate state references, don't mutate props. Don't mutate object references that will become part of state.

> Or can it be safely done?

Officially, no, not really. Technically... sort of... you do this by creating a new object reference and copying (*deep copy/clone*) the object properties. This isn't mutation though.